# Give weights for individual tensorflow datasets in a concatenated dataset for multiple datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I have 3 binary classification datasets. Let's call them `X`, `Y`, `Z`.

I then concatenate them into a single dataset for training.

```
ds = X.concatenate(Y).concatenate(Z).shuffle(buffer_size=10000).batch(64)
```

What I want to do is, give dataset X a higher weight in the loss function calculation so that an error in dataset `X` is more important than the rest of datasets.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: concat the weights to each label and use it during loss calculation step.